# How to call a C function from PL/SQL

Tags: c, oracle, plsql

I have a compiled C program which includes multiple functions. I would like to call functions in that C program from PL/SQL. Here's what I did:

Load compiled C program as an Oracle library (compiled C program copied to $ORACLE_HOME/bin/:

```
create or replace library startoo_lib
    as '/apps/oracle/product/19.3/dbhome_1/bin/ooffice.so';
```

Create function calling the library/C program, the function within the C program is defined as `bool oo_startup(string strHost, int port, bool bVisible)`

```
create or replace FUNCTION oo_startup(oo_host in varchar2, ooport in number)
return BOOLEAN
as external
library startoo_lib
name "oo_startup"
language c;
```

Call the function from sqlplus:

```
SQL> select oo_startup(shemp,8110) from dual;
select oo_startup(shemp,8110) from dual
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "SHEMP": invalid identifier


SQL> select oo_startup('shemp',8110) from dual;
select oo_startup('shemp',8110) from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00902: invalid datatype
```

I am not sure what I'm doing incorrectly, and am very new to PL/SQL. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: A select list item cannot return a boolean datatype. You can, however, make use of them in PL/SQL blocks. Make your function return a varchar2 and it should be ok. Something like 'Y' or 'N' would do the trick.

Comment: You certainly can go the route of an external library.  Assuming you're dealing with a recent version of Oracle, though, I think most people would try to use the `dbms_scheduler` package's ability to run external executables https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g rather than using an external library if possible.  There may still be a reason that you really want it to be an external library, of course, but if you haven't looked at executable jobs, that's probably an easier approach.